# Javascript :Ringtone is not playing

Tags: javascript, voip, sipml

In java script i add

```js
 function startRingTone() {
            try { ringtone.play(); }
            catch (e) { }
        }

        function stopRingTone() {
            try { ringtone.pause(); }
            catch (e) { }
        }
```

```html
    <audio id="ringtone" loop src="sounds/ringtone.mp3"> </audio>
```

whenever i call function startringtone();

Sound is not working.

my mp3 file is under sounds/ringtone.mp3.

and I am using MVC 4 so any another additional things needed?

Comment: an which magic does map your audio element ? How do you get this element? Show all code

Comment: Where did you defined `ringtone.` ?

Comment: what do you got in your catch?

Comment: i have defined my ringtone id in html page and i use inline javascript .